# How to connect postgresql with Xamarin?

Tags: postgresql, xamarin

does anyone know if I can connect postgresql in Xamarin? Please guide me, thank you.

Comment: Don't connect directly to postgresql, create an API you communicate through.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/

Comment: @Cheesebaron like using Xampp server connecting with postgresql ?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do so. It could be a RESTful API, gRPC, GraphQL, WebSockets or whatever you prefer. Thing is that databases should rarely, if ever, be exposed to the Internet.

Comment: @Cheesebaron noted and gratitude !